# Update Record with Composite Key - Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I am having an issue updating a record with a composite key using EF Core 5 and Net Core 5. I am able to get the record using both parts of the composite key (two ids in my case) but when I save the changes to the database I get the following error:

Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 24 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

After looking in the database, it looks like entity framework is trying to update all the records in the table with same id (first part of the composite key) instead of updating the record that I got.

Has anyone else seen this behavior? Any ideas of how to get around it or what I might be doing wrong?

Here is a basic version of the table set up

Table1:

```
Id (PK)
```

Table2:

```
Id (PK),  
Table1Id (PK, FK)
```

Scenario where it fails:

Table1:

```
Id  
--
1  
2
```

Table2:

```
Id, Table1Id  
------------
1, 1  
2, 1  
1, 2  
2, 2
```

If I try to update the first record in Table2 (1, 1), EF would try to update it and the third record (1, 2) and throw the above error.

Code:

```
// Getting record    
var record = await context.Table2s
                          .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == 1 && e.Table1Id == 1, cancellationToken);

// Saving
await context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

// I have also tried specifying which record to update before saving
context.Table2s.Update(record);
```

Configuration for Table2:

```
builder.ToTable("Table2");
builder.HasKey(e => new { e.Id, e.Table1Id });

builder.HasOne(e => e.Table1)
                .WithMany(m => m.Table2s)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.Table1Id)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Comment: Show us the code you've written to perform the record update.

Comment: I just added my code. Let me know if more is needed. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it seems pretty clear to me that EF is going to rely on a primary key of some sort to perform the code you've written correctly.  There's no workaround that I know of, short of writing a custom query or providing an actual primary key (and not a composite key).

Comment: Oof, can you fix your formatting of your question a bit? Looks like youre trying to draw a table but it's fallen apart

Comment: @RobertHarvey are you saying EF cannot understand composite primary keys? I thought it could..  Ctrl-F for `.HasKey(c => new { c.State, c.LicensePlate });` in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: I think you're reading a bit too much into the comment I posted.  Generally speaking, I don't like to rely on composite keys and natural keys; EF is specifically designed to naturally work with surrogate keys.

Comment: @DrewJ show us your OnModelCreating for this entity youre trying to save. Also, none of the code here does anything that triggers EF's desire to save (causes no changes to tracked entities). *I have also tried ... Update* -  `Update` is not for saving data

Comment: (There's some kind of bug with the SO table markdown where it looks fine in preview but is carp when posted.. Seems to be triggered by putting e.g. Table1 heading too close to the table. Try separating it from the table with a blank line and prefix the header with ### to make it a header)

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. @CaiusJard I just removed the table markdown as I couldn't get it to display correctly after saving.  I also added the configuration for Table2

Comment: @RobertHarvey so it sounds like the only other option would be to use a package like Dapper to execute raw sql to update the record. Seems odd EF can get the record but not update it.

Comment: In your startup, where you have `services.AddDbContext(options ... UseSqlServer()` can you add `.EnableSensitiveDataLogging().LogTo(Console.WriteLine, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Information)` chained onto the UseSqlServer call - it'll allow us to see the SQL being generated. I'd like to know if it's genning `UPDATE table2 SET .. WHERE Id = ...` (and if so, why is the fluent config of the compound key being ignored)

Comment: @DrewJ: EF supports raw SQL queries.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql).

Comment: have tried reversing the configuration to `'HasMany(x=> x.Table2s).WithOne(x=> x.Table1)`?

Comment: @CaiusJard I output the logs and EF is only including the Id in the where clause (WHERE [Id] = 1)

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce your complaint so far; my test database setup that replicates yours saves without issue. Give the code that you're using to modify the entity before you save

Comment: *I have also tried specifying which record to update* - that's not what Update is for, btw; leave Update alone

Answer (score 0):

It works in my own projects, I hope it will be useful.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb) {
   mb.Entity<WebServisUser>().HasKey(x => new
   {
       x.Proje, /* Composite Keys */
       x.KulAdi /* Composite Keys */
   });
   mb.Entity<WebServisUser>().Property(e => e.Proje).IsUnicode(false);
   mb.Entity<WebServisUser>().Property(e => e.KulAdi).IsUnicode(false);
}
```

I have added the link other functions for better understanding.

```
public static class Helper
    {
        public static bool IsNull(this object value) => (value == null || Convert.IsDBNull(value) || Convert.GetTypeCode(value) == TypeCode.Empty);
        public static bool IsNotNull(this object value) => !value.IsNull();
        public static string ToPropertyName(this Expression value)
        {
            if (typeof(LambdaExpression).IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType())) { value = ((LambdaExpression)value).Body; }
            if (value is MemberExpression e_mem) { return e_mem.Member.Name; }
            else if (value is UnaryExpression e_una) { return ((MemberExpression)e_una.Operand).Member.Name; }
            else { throw new InvalidCastException(String.Format("value type can be \"{0}\" or \"{1}\"", nameof(MemberExpression), nameof(UnaryExpression))); }
        }
        public static object ChangeType(object value, Type type)
        {
            var c = TryTypeIsNullable(type, out Type _outtype);
            return (c && value.IsNull()) ? null : (_outtype.IsEnum ? Enum.ToObject(_outtype, value) : Convert.ChangeType(value, c ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) : type));
        }
        public static void SetPropertyValue<T>(this T value, string propertyname, object data) where T : class
        {
            var p = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyname);
            p.SetValue(value, data.IsNull() ? null : ChangeType(data, p.PropertyType));
        }
        public static bool TryTypeIsNullable(Type value, out Type outvalue)
        {
            var t = (value.IsGenericType && value.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)));
            outvalue = (t ? value.GenericTypeArguments[0] : value); return t;
        }
        public static bool TryTypeIsAttribute<T, Y>(T value, out Y outvalue) where T : ICustomAttributeProvider where Y : Attribute
        {
            bool ret;
            try
            {
                var v = value.GetType();
                var y = typeof(Y);
                if (typeof(Assembly).IsAssignableFrom(v) && Attribute.IsDefined((Assembly)((object)value), y)) { ret = true; }
                else if (typeof(MemberInfo).IsAssignableFrom(v) && Attribute.IsDefined((MemberInfo)((object)value), y)) { ret = true; }
                else if (typeof(Module).IsAssignableFrom(v) && Attribute.IsDefined((Module)((object)value), y)) { ret = true; }
                else if (typeof(ParameterInfo).IsAssignableFrom(v) && Attribute.IsDefined((ParameterInfo)((object)value), y)) { ret = true; }
                else { ret = false; }
                outvalue = ret ? value.GetCustomAttributes(y, false).Cast<Y>().Take(1).FirstOrDefault() : default;
            }
            catch
            {
                outvalue = default;
                ret = false;
            }
            return ret;
        }
        public static void SetCompositeKey<T, TKey>(this DbContext context, T entity, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> compositekey, TKey compositekeyvalue, Action<T> actionislem = null) where T : class, new()
        {
            var t = typeof(T);
            var c = compositekey.ToPropertyName();
            var ie_prop = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(x => x.GetMethod.IsNotNull() && x.SetMethod.IsNotNull() && !x.GetMethod.IsVirtual && !x.SetMethod.IsVirtual && !Helper.TryTypeIsAttribute(x, out NotMappedAttribute _)).Select(x => new
            {
                name = x.Name,
                iskey = x.Name == c,
                iscompositekey = Helper.TryTypeIsAttribute(x, out KeyAttribute _outkeyvalue) && _outkeyvalue.IsNotNull() && Helper.TryTypeIsAttribute(x, out DatabaseGeneratedAttribute _outdatagenvalue) && _outdatagenvalue.DatabaseGeneratedOption == DatabaseGeneratedOption.None
            });
            if (ie_prop.Where(x => x.iscompositekey).Count() < 2) { throw new KeyNotFoundException("minimum of 2 composite keys exception message..."); }
            else if (ie_prop.Any(x => x.iscompositekey && x.iskey))
            {
                var addentity = new T();
                var e = context.Entry<T>(entity);
                var dbset = context.Set<T>();
                dbset.Attach(entity);
                foreach (var item in ie_prop.Select(x => new
                {
                    x.name,
                    x.iskey
                })) { addentity.SetPropertyValue(item.name, item.iskey ? compositekeyvalue : e.Property(item.name).OriginalValue); }
                dbset.Add(addentity); /* Insert record about new key value */
                if (actionislem.IsNotNull()) { actionislem(addentity); } /* If there are other areas of connection, do the operations there with the action method. */
                dbset.Remove(entity); /* delete old value */
            }
            else { throw new Exception("compositekey must be composite key exception message..."); }
        }
    }
```

and example

```
using (var mdl = new mdlBayUniOrtak())
            {
                using (var c = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    var beforeentity = mdl.WebServisUsers.Where(x => x.Proje == "loremipsum").Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
                    var e = new Action<WebServisUser>((WebServisUser afterentity) =>
                    {
                        /* Other actions if necessary. Other foreign key operations can be done here! */
                    });
                    mdl.SetCompositeKey(beforeentity, x => x.KulAdi, "galatasaray", e);
                    mdl.SaveChanges();
                    c.Complete();
                }
            }
```